# How to make interactive buttons that scrolls vertical divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Lets say I have these divs that are products and

```
<div class="container">
                <div class="product">
                    <div class="image"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.shingpoint.com.pk/Images/Thumbnails/pc-a1-470-59100-080316082835.jpg"/></div>
                    <div class="description"><h4 class="productname">ASUS VivoMini PC - UN65H-M030M</h4></div>
                    <div class="price">
                        <span>Rs. 37,900</span>
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Details"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product">
                    <div class="image"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.shingpoint.com.pk/Images/Thumbnails/pc-a1-470-59100-080316082835.jpg"/></div>
                    <div class="description"><h4 class="productname">ASUS VivoMini PC - UN65H-M030M</h4></div>
                    <div class="price">
                        <span>Rs. 37,900</span>
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Details"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

There are only 2 products due to 'stackoverflow restriction of mostly-code'. Lets say there are 10 of these products and I want to display 5 of them and rest would be shown one by one as per click on forward and backward buttons just like facebook have when viewing photos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your `class='container` div to a specific height. If your items' height is, let say, `200px` you can set your container to `400px`. Then on button click you can scroll container div. Your code will look like this:

```
<script>

function scrollOneItem(){
    var container = document.getElementByClassName('container');
    container.scrollTop = container.scrollHeight + 200;
}

</script>

<button onClick="scrollOneItem()">Scroll down</button>
<div class="container">
...
</div>
```